# Extract return string parameter values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a request that looks like this ;

```
url = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&TOKEN=#{transaction.token}
                        &PAYERID=#{transaction.payer_id}&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION=sale"
url = CGI.escape(url)
uri = URI(url)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

and `res.body` looks like this; `TOKEN=EC%2d7UM71457T34680821&TIMESTAMP=2013%2d11%2d03T21%3a19%3a11Z&CORRELATIONID=3b73c396244ff&ACK=Success&VERSION=98&BUILD=8334781`

How can i get  the `TOKEN` and `ACK` values from the string? am not sure `params` works here?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body is URI-encoded, just like GET (or some POST) params. You could unpack it manually, by doing something like this:

```
require 'uri'

# body takes place of res.body for this example
body = 'TOKEN=EC%2d7UM71457T34680821&TIMESTAMP=2013%2d11%2d03' +    
  'T21%3a19%3a11Z&CORRELATIONID=3b73c396244ff&AC' + 
  'K=Success&VERSION=98&BUILD=8334781'

# First split into key/value pairs, and use inject to start building a hash
results = body.split('&').inject( {} ) do |hash,kv| 

  # Split each key/value pair
  k,v = kv.split('=').map do |uri_encoded_value| 
    # Decode - innermost loop, because it may contain encoded '&' or '='
    URI.decode(uri_encoded_value)
  end

  # Add to hash we are building with inject
  hash[k] = v
  hash
end

=> {"TOKEN"=>"EC-7UM71457T34680821", "TIMESTAMP"=>"2013-11-03T21:19:11Z",
 "CORRELATIONID"=>"3b73c396244ff", "ACK"=>"Success", "VERSION"=>"98", 
 "BUILD"=>"8334781"}
```

---

Actually though `URI` can do nearly all of this for you (and deal with variations in the format better than above), with the `decode_www_form` class method.

```
params = {}
URI.decode_www_form( body ).each do |k,v|
  params[k] = v
end
params
=> {"TOKEN"=>"EC-7UM71457T34680821", "TIMESTAMP"=>"2013-11-03T21:19:11Z",
 "CORRELATIONID"=>"3b73c396244ff", "ACK"=>"Success", "VERSION"=>"98", 
 "BUILD"=>"8334781"}
```